# SessionManager equivalent in Facebook SDK 4

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

What is the equivalent of SessionManager and simple session in Facebook SDK 4 for Android ? How I can check something like this in 3.x ?

```
SessionManager mSessionManager = new SessionManager(SplashActivity.this);
if( mSessionManager.isLoggedIn() )
```

Every help will be apreciated.

Comment: you can use Accesstoken for sdk 4.0

Comment: could you write equivalent part of code?

Comment: yes i am uploading answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with AccessToken

```
private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;



    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken newAccessToken) {
            updateWithToken(newAccessToken);
        }
    };




private void updateWithToken(AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

    if (currentAccessToken != null) {
        //redirect to your activity

    } else {

    // your sign in code

}
```

On logout you can clear the `token`.

Comment: And what is equivalent for Session session = Session.getActiveSession(); because I cannot come up with AccessToken ?

Comment: Equivalent for seesion is `LoginManager` . Read this `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/`. And for session it is removed from sdk 4.0. 
So you have to use `AccessToken` instead of `session`.